# Probability of A or B and conditional probability

Tags: probability

Given that $P(A)=0.5$    ; $P(B)=0.6$; $P(A \cup B')=0.7$

1. Calculate $P(A \cup B)$.
2. What is the probability of A given that B has not happened.

**Attempt**

$P(A \cup B)=1-P(A \cup B')=1-0.7=0.3$

and

$P(A|B')=\dfrac{P(A \cap B')}{P(B')}=\dfrac{P(A)-P(A \cap B)}{P(B')}$

But I can't find the value of $P(A \cap B)$.

Comment: Please Tick mark at the answer which you consider most preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You have $P(A), P(B)$ and $P(A \cup B)$
Use the formula, $P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)=P(A \cup B)$ 
  [Above formula can be derived by using venn diagrams.]

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: You've got the expression for $P(A \cup B)$ wrong. $P(A \cup B) = 1-P(A' \cap B').$ But this is not required anyway.

**Hint**: $P(B') = 1-P(B)$. Also, you have  $P(A \cup B') = P(A) + P(B') - P (A \cap B')$.
From this, you can get $P (A \cap B')$, and thus $P(A|B')$. Now you can easily get $P(A \cap B)$, and from that, $P(A \cup B)$.